# How to automatically add rel="noopener" to a target="_blank" link?

Tags: javascript

I have a little JS that include target="_blank" to all external link. For security reasons I need to append also rel="noopener".

Any help to achieve this goal?

My script:

```js
(function($) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    add_target_blank_to_external_links();
  });

  function add_target_blank_to_external_links() {
    $('a[href^="http://"], a[href^="https://"]').not('a[href*="' + location.hostname + '"]').attr('target', '_blank');
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You're already doing `.attr('target','_blank')`, just follow the same pattern to set a `rel` attribute?

Comment: `$('a[href^="http"]').not('a[href*="' + location.hostname + '"]').attr('target', '_blank').attr('rel', 'noopener');`

Comment: Thank you Snow, this way?   
a[href^="https://"]').not('a[href*="'+location.hostname+'"]').attr('target','_blank').attr('rel','noopener');

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: You can also do it with one call: `.attr({target: "_blank", rel: "noopener"})`

Answer (score 6):

So, your final solution is like below.

N.B. It's very good practice to use `rel="noopener"` because it prevents the new page from reaching back to control the initial page. you can also use like `rel="noreferrer"`

```js
(function($) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    add_target_blank_to_external_links();
  });

  function add_target_blank_to_external_links() {
    $('a[href^="http"]').not('a[href*="' + location.hostname + '"]').attr({target: "_blank", rel: "noopener"});
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">Demo link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One small improvement to labu4bd's answer above (very useful, thank you!) is to change the initial filter to only amend links in the body so they are not added to style & script links in the head.

For example:

```
(function($) {
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    add_target_blank_to_external_links();
  });

  function add_target_blank_to_external_links() {
    $('body a[href^="http"]').not('a[href*="' + location.hostname + '"]').attr({target: "_blank", rel: "noopener"});
  }
})(jQuery);
```